# Missing dates program

Tags: c#, date, io

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the path where the text file can be found");
string path = Console.ReadLine();

string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\InputFile.txt");

string[] dates = text.Split('\n');

for (int i = 0; i < dates.Length; i++)
{
    if (dates[i] != "" && dates[i] != null)
    {
        dates[i] = dates[i].Remove(dates[i].Length - 1);
    }
}
for (int j = 0; j < dates.Length; j++)
{
    if (dates[j] != "" && dates[j] != null)
    {
        DateTime currentdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dates[j-1]);
        DateTime futuredate = Convert.ToDateTime(dates[j]);

        if (currentdate.AddDays(1) != futuredate)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" {0} {1}", currentdate.AddDays(1).ToShortDateString(), currentdate.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program it gives me an error:

> DateTime currentdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dates[j-1]); "Index was outside the bounds of the array."

Comment: Protip: Use `File.ReadAllLines` instead

Comment: another question how do you remove all the dates where it is a saturday or sunday? Dates are recieved from a text file in the format yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: "currentdate.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek" only shows one day: "Saturday" plz help

Comment: You want multiple days of the week for a single date??? `/o\\`

Answer (score 1):

You're starting your loop at index `0`.

`0 - 1` is `-1`.

There is item at index `-1` hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Well when `j` is `0` you are going to have a problem.

Answer (score 0):

When j = 0, j-1 = -1

dates[-1] is outside of the bounds of the array. You'll need to do something special when j=0

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
 DateTime currentdate = Convert.ToDateTime(dates[j-1]);
```

On iteration `j=0`, the index is being resolved as `dates[j-1]` and `j-1 == -1`

You need to correct how this loop checks the first element of this array.